# How can I send a udp packet with dynamic HEX values

Tags: sockets, char, udp, buffer

I need to send a UDP packet with HEX values like this example;

```
char buffer[4]={0x22,0x00,0x0d,0xf4};
```

However, I need to be able to change the hex values in code.

```
hex1 = "0x83";
hex2 = "0x11";
hex3 = "0x00";
hex4 = "0x01";
char buffer[4]={hex1, hex2, hex3, hex4}
```

I have tried the example above but it does not work. Can you show me the correct way to build the buffer for sending.

Comment: hex1 = 0x83 not "0x83". 0x83 is a number value, "0x83" is char* with five elements :-)

Comment: I guess I was just over thinking it. Simple fix  for a simple problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and fill the buffer separately.  And remove the quotes around your hex values.

```
char buffer[4];
buffer[0] = 0x83;
buffer[1] = 0x11;
buffer[2] = 0x00;
buffer[3] = 0x01;
```